# GridView item position changing position dynamically while scrolling

Tags: android, gridview

I am using gridview layout for displaying multiple item and items are displaying fine, if I check on the big screen then all work done is fine because no scrolling is required.
But if I user small screen while scrolling it changing position dynamically.
** Example:** 
 If I display 50 items it working fine if I display 1000 items I need to scroll down, on that time selected items are changing their positions dynamically.

**Adapter Code**

```
public class EM_event_total_userseatsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EM_event_total_UserSeatsModel> implements View.OnClickListener {
ArrayList<EM_event_total_UserSeatsModel> dataSet;
public ArrayList<Integer> EMeventuserseatslist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Context mContext;
ViewHolder holder;
String user_seats;
private int[] tagCollection;
private String[] mobileValues;
private  String[] mobileValuesD;
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView TvEmUserSeats;
    ImageView IvUsreSeats,available,selctedimag;

}

private String[] strings;
List<Integer> selectedPositions = new ArrayList<>();
SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;

public 
 EM_event_total_userseatsAdapter(ArrayList<EM_event_total_UserSeatsModel> data, Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_em_get_seats, data);
    this.dataSet = data;
    this.mContext=context;


    selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
}

public int getTagFromPosition(int position) {
    return tagCollection[position];
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int position=(Integer) v.getTag();
    Object object= getItem(tagCollection[position]);

    EM_event_total_UserSeatsModel dataModel=(EM_event_total_UserSeatsModel) 
 object;
   }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    EM_event_total_UserSeatsModel dataModel = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

    final View result;


    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_em_get_seats, parent, false);


        viewHolder.TvEmUserSeats = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TvEmUserSeats);
        viewHolder.IvUsreSeats = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.IvUsreSeats);


        result=convertView;

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result=convertView;
    }

    String blue_available = "seat3.png";
    String red_booked = "seat1.png";

    String get_seat = dataModel.getBookedStatus();
    viewHolder.TvEmUserSeats.setText(dataModel.getSeatName());

    //holder.imgSeatSelected.setVisibility(isSelected(position) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    if(Integer.parseInt(get_seat) == 1){
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(main_url+"assets/admin/img/" + red_booked).into(viewHolder.IvUsreSeats);

    }else
    {

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(main_url+"assets/admin/img/" + blue_available).into(viewHolder.IvUsreSeats);

    }
    return convertView;
}

public void toggleSelection(int position) {
    if (selectedItems.get(position, false)) {
        selectedItems.delete(position);
    } else {
        selectedItems.put(position, true);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clearSelections() {
    selectedItems.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getSelectedItemCount() {
    return selectedItems.size();
}

public String getSelectedItems() {
    String items = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
        items += selectedItems.keyAt(i);

    }

    return items;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you find the answer

Comment: No i changed to recycler grid, its working